# Azure Search - Error in creating indexer

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

I am following this [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/create-indexer) link to create an azure indexer but it is showing below error. I am able to create the datasource and index but not indexer. It says it is not able to parse connection string but there is no where I can provide connection string.

Invoke-WebRequest : {"error":{"code":"","message":"Connection string could not be parsed. 
It must be in one of the following formats: 
'DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=[your storage account];AccountKey=[your 
account key];' or 'BlobEndpoint=[your blob endpoint URI];SharedAccessSignature=[your 
account shared access token];' or 'ContainerSharedAccessUri=[your container shared access 
token with read and list permissions]'"}}
At line:15 char:17
+ ... $response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $indexerApiUrl -Headers $RequestHe ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest 
   ) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands 
   .InvokeWebRequestCommand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error refers to the connection string you used to create the *datasource*. That connection string is fully validated only when creating the indexer. Update your datasource with a valid connection string, and try creating the indexer again.

Comment: Perfect! ThanQ very much. I struggled almost a day 

Not sure what was the problem with below connection string,

$connectionString = @{"connectionString" = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=$StorageAccountName;AccountKey=$key;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net;Connection Timeout=30;"}

I just modified it to below one and updated the datasource:
$connectionString = @{"connectionString" = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=$StorageAccountName;AccountKey=$key;}

Now the indexer got created. I only removed 2 arguments from connection string. could you please explain?

Comment: Probably `Connection Timeout` is not a thing for Storage connection strings. You might have copied it from a SQL connection string perhaps.